# How is Sajin Komamura a wolf?

Tags: bleach

Sajin Komamura is described as being an anthropomorphic wolf in the Wikipedia article, but everyone in the Soul Society is either someone who died or the descendant of someone who died.  There are (as far as I know) no anthropomorphic wolves in the living world, so where did he come from? Was he born that way, created, or is there some other explanation?

[image]

Comment: It hasn't been revealed yet.

Comment: well, if you read  http://www.bleachanime.org/forums/showthread.php?t=194 it says that he was severely burned ( could not find a real source confirming it though) . made allot of people start a theory it is just a transformation  " Yoruichi could stay being a cat if she wanted to."

Comment: @Dimitrimx: That was written in *2007*, I don't think it has much merit nowdays.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha still no other source has confirmed or proven it wrong sofar.

Comment: It's kind of obvious that he wasn't burned, since his face were revealed, also see Oded's answer to prove that it was a born trait.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bleach episode 539 has some answers.

Komamura is talking to his great grandfather:

[image]

> Who is a huge canine himself. From this it is clear that a canine appearance is a family trait. The conversation also reveals that they do have a special status, though it is not clear what exactly their role in Soul Society is. It is, however, clear that Komamura was born this way.

---

Bleach 556 has some further information - in a flashback to his previous encounter with his great grandfather, who says:

> [image: werewolf clan!]

---

> So, he is not a wolf, but a werewolf. The clan originated in soul society, were banished, but did come back.

Answer (score -1):

My guess that Komamura is some form of mutated soul but idk all I know is some soul reapers have a unique appearance and not all soul reapers look like humans but to be honest idk maybe it’s the soul equivalent of werewolf conditions

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. We appreciate your contribution, but pure opinion/speculation answer is discouraged. Instead, please [edit] and try to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.